# How to enforce return all possible keys of type in array

Tags: typescript

I have the following type:

```
type Fruit = "Banana" | "Melon" | "Apple";
```

I want to create a function that will return all of the possible keys of `Fruit`. Something like:

```
function getAllFruits(): Fruit[] {
  return ["Banana", "Melon"]; // <-- Should throw an error due to missing "Apple".
}
```

The reason I want to do so is that I want to make sure no one will forget to add the following values to the array.

Another approach would be to go the opposite way - create a function that returns all of the types and then setting the type `Fruit` as the return type of the function. In any case, I'm not interested in that approach.

Any ideas?

#### Update 1

I would like to see a solution that doesn't involve enums (if possible).

Comment: @derpirscher I was interested to see a solution without enums

Comment: Why dont to use just:  type Fruit = ["Banana", "Melon" , "Apple"] ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Because I want the function values to be inferred by the type and not the opposite. In essence, the type is the one that should decide what values should be and not the function.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to go about it.

1. Generate all possible permutations in compile-time.
2. Create a smart identity function that requires all colors to be provided to it.

The first solution does not scale. It requires TypeScript to generate n! tuples, and you will quickly hit the limitations of the type system. That's why I recommend using the second approach.

```
type Fruit = "Banana" | "Melon" | "Apple";

function getAllFruits(): Fruit[] {
  return enumerate<Fruit>()('Apple', 'Banana', 'Melon');
}
```

Helper types:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type NonEmptyArray<T> = [T, ...T[]]

type MustInclude<T, U extends T[]> =
  [T] extends [ValueOf<U>]
    ? U
    : never;

const enumerate = <T,>() =>
  <U extends NonEmptyArray<T>>(...elements: MustInclude<T, U>) =>
    elements;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=56&pln=4&pc=48#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigIgEIEMB2BumUAPlgLIQA2A9vieZgIJhjUSYDcAUDwGYJ8AY2BJ6UAOYRgzatXjJgAZwAUASgBcsRCgDaAXSgBvHlChwZCOPigR8CALYQ4uYBAA8ilAD4NqgHJWdggAgBooALxCQnDIqjp8APVeAF8%20UEgoADVcagQIAHl%20DwAVH3QoUr0AawgQWn4qg14eTOgAOXoAUUcwUGY4VxAyiow9UoiAOhnqgwMM8GgKBGVgAEkRfIATT0moAFU7AA93fG3lKsMxsygJowhT%20wu73PyikoOfBfNzAH5DrdzNp8BAAG4uVrCehrOwOZyudyVMphPzqdA%20W4eI6PM4vLr4Xr9ECDYajPwzKY0CDOfAqbQrNabYQ7PYRL7otCY352Di0lRcIA)

Notice that if you remove a fruit from `getAllFruits`, the compiler will yell at you. This method keeps the implementation in sync with the model.

Comment: This is really nice. One small thing - when I remove a fruit from `getAllFruits` the error I'm getting isn't quite helpful (`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`) Any chance of fixing that?

Comment: Very good answer, I have learn a lot ! Thanks

Comment: @EliyaCohen I agree, the error message is not informative at all. I haven't found a way to make it better, unfortunately.