# Can I get a list of field names of an interface whose types are of a given type?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

For example, if I have this interface

```
interface Measurement {
  date: Date
  width: number
  height: number
  depth: number
  comment: string
}
```

Is there a way for me to get the following?

```
const numericFields = ['width', 'height', 'depth']
const dateFields = ['date']
const stringFields = ['comment']
```

Alternatively, is there a way I can create a function like the following?

```
// not sure about the signature, but hopefully you get the idea
function getInterfaceFieldsWithType<I, T>: keyof I[]

const numericFields = getInterfaceFieldsWithType<Measurement, number>()
```

Answer (score 0):

**First very naive approach:**

```js
interface Measurement {
  date: Date
  width: number
  height: number
  depth: number
  comment: string
}

type GetByType<T, V> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends V ? P : never
}[keyof T]

/**
 * Just an alias to reduce repetitive code
 */
type Get<T> = Array<GetByType<Measurement, T>>

const numericFields: Get<number> = ['width', 'height', 'depth']
const dateFields: Get<Date> = ['date']
const stringFields: Get<string> = ['comment']
```

Drawbacks:

```js
const numericFields: Get<number> = ['width', 'height', 'depth', 'depth', 'width'] // valid from TS perpective
```

If you want to forbid dublications by TS, you can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64739939/how-to-enforce-return-all-possible-keys-of-type-in-array)

If you want to be 100% sure that there are no dublications in runtime, the best way is to use `Set's`:

```js
const array = [...new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 4])] // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Second approach**

```js
interface Measurement {
  date: Date
  width: number
  height: number
  depth: number
  comment: string
}

// filter all properies
type GetByType<T, V> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends V ? P : never
}[keyof T]

/**
 * Just an alias to reduce repetitive code
 */
type Result = GetByType<Measurement, string>
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]


/**
 * because our second argument is stringified type name,
 * we need some sort of vice-versa mapping 
 */
type LiteralToType<T> = T extends 'string' ? string : T extends 'number' ? number : T extends 'Date' ? Date : never;
type TypeToLiteral<T> = T extends string ? 'string' : T extends number ? 'number' : T extends Date ? 'Date' : never;

const getInterfaceFieldsWithType = <
  Obj extends Record<string, unknown>,
  Type extends TypeToLiteral<Values<Obj>> // I need a guarantee that we have at least one property with expected type
>(obj: Obj, expectedType: Type): GetByType<Obj, LiteralToType<Type>>[] => {
  const keys = (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof Obj>)
  /**
   * Here, filter is a typescript guard
   * It says: if I return true, then you can sleep well, this key is what you need
   */
  return keys.filter((elem): elem is GetByType<Obj, LiteralToType<Type>> => typeof obj[elem] === expectedType)
}

/**
 * Tests
 */

const result = getInterfaceFieldsWithType({ date: '01-01-2021', width: 24, height: 42, numberdepth: 2, comment: 'hello' }, 'number') // ok ("width" | "height" | "numberdepth")[]
const result2 = getInterfaceFieldsWithType({ date: new Date(), width: 24, height: 42, numberdepth: 2, comment: 'hello' }, 'Date') // ok "date"[]
const result3 = getInterfaceFieldsWithType({ date: new Date(), width: 24, height: 42, numberdepth: 2, comment: 'hello' }, 'string') // ok "comment"[]
const result4 = getInterfaceFieldsWithType({ date: new Date(), width: 24, height: 42, numberdepth: 2, comment: 'hello' }, 'Promise') // error
```

If you still want to allow non existence property types, like `Promise`, you can add next Overloading to your function

```js
type EmptyArray = readonly string[];

interface Overloading {
  <
    Obj extends Record<string, unknown>,
    Type extends TypeToLiteral<Values<Obj>> //I need a guarantee that we have at least one property with expected type
    >(obj: Obj, expectedType: Type): ReadonlyArray<GetByType<Obj, LiteralToType<Type>>>
  <
    Obj extends Record<string, unknown>,
    Type extends string // I need a guarantee that we have at least one property with expected type
    >(obj: Obj, expectedType: Type): EmptyArray
}
```